# Rewriting old formated URL to new Formated URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am actually trying to have the URL repointed via HTAccess using the Old Formating of the website:

```
https://fw1.work/actualites/details.php?ID=3191
```

to the new Formating. To do so I need to point it to the New URL Formating:

```
https://fw1.work/actualite.php?id=3191
```

Actually tried a couple of things online but nothing seems to be working the way I want it...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^actualites/details.php /actualite.php?id=%1 [L]
```

This is where I am at actually.

Answer (score 0):

make sure rewrite mod enabled,
then let RewriteRule rgexp match the full url.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=(\w+)$
    RewriteRule ^actualites/details.php(.*) /actualite.php?id=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the rules as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^actualite.php$ actualites/details.php?ID=%1 [L]
```